# Instagram Images usingn .net 6 mvc

Tags: .net, instagram

So on the view, I am using for this, I have copied an embeded image from Instagram to add to my site. The issue I am having is that it is throwing an error because the embedded version used an @NameOfInstagramAccount. So it is not allowing me to use that. Is there a way I can change that

```html
<p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/CjLy3aqO-Cw/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading" style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">A post shared by Mely&#39;s Underground-Cuisine (@InstagramAccount)</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Yes there is more to t he embedded image but this is the part that is making it error out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that since I never needed to use this before, all I had to do was add a second @. So it would `@@InstagramAccount` I am so happy I for discord.